# Analysis of binary files / alternative to 101 editor's "binary templates"

Tags: windows, gratis, editor, hex-viewer

Until today when I had to look at binary files, I did that with [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/de/hxd/). Since this were single non-repetitive actions I had to perform, this was sufficient for me. However, the upcoming task requires that I look a certain binary file more often and interpret and modify the contents (I'm working in QA).

While the file format was developed in-house, there's neither a tool available from our development department that would parse the file for me and display it in a human readable format nor a tool to modify single items.

On my search for such a tool, I found [101 Editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) which has "binary templates" which looks very much like what I need, i.e. I tell the hex editor how to interpret the file (boolean, int, long etc.) and the editor then provides a nice way to display and modify the values.

That tool should work on Windows and be gratis.

Comment: I would be happy ot develop such a tool on a consultancy basis :-)

Comment: @Mawg: that's totally fine, since it's tagged gratis, you can develop it for free :-D

Comment: lol - as can whoever came up with it in house. But, since they won't, my offer stands :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hexinator](https://hexinator.com/)

- has a similar feature to binary templates that is called a grammar. It allows to insert numbers, strings, structs and binary blobs. If that's not enough, it has scripting capabilities in Python and Lua
- the values can then be edited nicely (e.g. in decimal instead of hex). The hex area can be highlighted.
- works on Windows
- is supposed to be a test version gratis, but if I understand the [EULA](https://hexinator.com/eula/) correctly, there's nothing that prevents you from using it for a longer period of time.

Drawbacks:

it seems to have issues with more than one open grammar + one open file. When opening a second file for the same grammer, it crashed. Save early and save often.

Screenshot of a partially analyzed file:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: very buggy indeed

Answer (score 0):

I use my Binary Editor for this kind of task.
Seems to meet stated requirements of decoding files, editing, running on Windows.
http://www.nyangau.org/be/be.htm

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mention it in my question, but I expected something with a user interface.

Comment: It has a textual user interface, rather than a graphical one. To see it, look at 9:40 in https://youtu.be/wXxisSPAZhk